# How do I solve the Continued Fraction $[1,x,x^2,x^3,\ldots]$

Tags: number-theory, conjectures, continued-fractions

My function $M(x)$ is defined as $$M(x)=1+\cfrac{x^0}{1+\cfrac{x^1}{1+\cfrac{x^2}{1+\cfrac{x^3}{1+\cfrac{x^4}{1+\cfrac{x^5}{1+\cfrac{x^{6}}{1+\cfrac{x^{7}}{1+\cfrac{x^{8}}{1+\cfrac{x^9}{1+\cfrac{x^{10}}{1+\ddots}}}}}}}}}}}$$

I understand the Rogers-Ramanujan Continued Fraction $R(a,q)$ is very similar but it is slightly different. I would like to know what $M(2)$ is, but I learned that any value $|q|>1$ starts to split and become two different values. **What are the decimal approximations of $M(2)$ for both $n$=even and $n$=odd and what are their exact values?**

This is my first question on this site so if it's janky or similar to an answer already I'm sorry.

Comment: I don't know what $R(a,q)$ is, but according to both [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rogers%E2%80%93Ramanujan_continued_fraction) and [MathWorld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Rogers-RamanujanContinuedFraction.html) the Rogers-Ramanujan continued fraction is $R(q)=q^{1/5}/(1+q/(1+q^2/(1+q^3/(1+\cdots))))$, so isn't your fraction just $q^{-1/5}R(q)$?

Comment: @Rahul You mean $1 + q^{-1/5}R(q)$.

Comment: @Unit Yes, thanks

Comment: Using Pari/GP and the following routine `f(x,ex=1)=local(cf); cf=1;forstep(k=ex,0,-1,cf=1+x^k/cf); return(cf)` I get for increasing exponents approximations to two accumulation-points
$$\begin{array} {r,r,|,r,r}
f(2.0,2) & 1.71428571429& f(2.0,3) & 1.41935483871 \\
f(2.0,32) &1.61037016501& f(2.0,33)& 1.47069476492 \\
f(2.0,132) &1.61036823964& f(2.0,133)& 1.47069594450 \\ f(2.0,232) & 1.61036823964 & f(2.0,233) & 1.47069594450
\end{array}$$

Comment: Mine is slightly different. Mine is $M(x) =$ $1+\cfrac{x^0}{1+\cfrac{x^1}{1+\cfrac{x^2}{1+\cfrac{x^3}{1+\cfrac{x^4}{1+\cfrac{x^5}{1+\cfrac{x^{6}}{1+\cfrac{x^{7}}{1+\cfrac{x^{8}}{1+\cfrac{x^9}{1+\cfrac{x^{10}}{1+\ddots}}}}}}}}}}}$       while Ramanujan's is $R(a,q) =$ $\cfrac{q^{1/5}}{1+\cfrac{q^1}{1+\cfrac{q^2}{1+\cfrac{q^3}{1+\cfrac{q^4}      {1+\cfrac{q^5}{1+\cfrac{q^{6}}{1+\cfrac{q^{7}}{1+\cfrac{q^{8}}{1+\cfrac{q^9}{1+\cfrac{q^{10}}{1+\ddots}}}}}}}}}}}$ I would also like to know if it is possible to find the exact values of $1.61036...$ and $1.47069...$ and what does the function look like?